# DevOps Query Across Projects

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking to create a cross-project query, but I want to be specific about which of our projects should be included.  I don't want all of the projects we have in Azure DevOps to be included.  However, there doesn't seem to be a "Project" field in the list of conditions.

Does anyone know of a way to create the query to run against multiple projects, but to restrict which projects are included in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, but left it here so that others may find it useful.

The field I needed is "Team Project" and this is only available when "Query Across Projects" is highlighted.  I was thrown by the name of the field, as it doesn't make sense to me to have the word "Team" at the front.

Comment: Please mark your answer as a correct one so that others who meet the same issue will find your excellent solution to help them. We will appreciate your good job on helping us make the work better and easier.